# Abstract and/or interface for public facing API for PHP classes

Tags: php, interface, abstract-class

I have a couple of classes which are in the `Entities` namespace. I have an interface `Entity.php` which has 3 methods; `parse($data)`, `getId()`, `__toString()`.

Now I was using the Car entity (which `implements Entity`) and when I went to type $entity-> I got autocompleted with the `parse()` method. Which makes sense, but what I really want is for that method not to be visible when used on higher levels (inside the views/pages).

So I tried to make that method protected, then tried to change that also in the interface, but it wouldn't let me; "php interface access type must be omitted".

What I want is to force developers to add parse, getId and __toString to their Entity implementations, but when 'users'/developers use the actual entities that they only see the visible API (which is the forced getId, __toString and other entity specific methods; getColor, getModel, etc..).

Should I do the following: `Car extends AbstractEntity` and `AbstractEntity implements Entity`?

Comment: Is your question about your IDE, or implementation?

Comment: If you don't want things to be available at 'higher levels', just make them part of a different interface. You can implement multiple interfaces

Comment: Both, I guess? parse() is only needed for people who build custom Entities, not for people who want to use the Car implementation

Comment: you could make a CustomEntity interface, and only implement that for classes you want to be custom, which have the parse() in them. This way, you could type-hint on Entity and match both custom and non-custom ones, but need to check if it's an instance of CustomEntity to know if it can parse()